# Convert one unicode to another with a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

Goal: Change the arrow to down on click.

I've tried using a different unicode in the Javascript to change it but I just get the basic string even when escaping via "\"...

Little lost. Hopefully its a simple question.

```js
$('.col-exp').on('click', function() {
  let th = $(this);
  th.children('span').text('***Change to down arrow***');
  th.next('section').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="col-exp">Employment<span>&#11206;</span></h2>
<section id="employment">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>FakeSystems Inc</td>
      <td>Master Developer</td>
      <td>2000-2010</td>
      <td>Managed API routing by coordinating with foo and assessing the accuracy of returned data from 3rd party partners</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WorseSystems Inc</td>
      <td>Lesser Developer</td>
      <td>1990-2000</td>
      <td>Made sites with Geocities and Angelfire that included tons of <code>blink</code> tags and gifs to make me look awesome</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
<h2 class="col-exp">Education<span>&#11206;</span></h2>
<section id="education">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Fake Institute of Fortitude</td>
      <td>1986-1990</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try .innerHTML instead of text

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally fine with using vanilla JS, but I should have added jQuery to the tags.

Comment: This would be easier with CSS and [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: *"I just get the basic string"* — What does that mean?

Comment: @deceze It means I wasn't using innerHTML or even .html, so it was literally putting my unicode into the span.

Comment: Please do not conflate "Unicode" and *HTML entities*…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) because it is one of a HTML entities.

Using `.text`, it will be taken as pure text, and will not be parsed as a HTML.

```js
$('.col-exp').on('click', function(){
  let th = $(this);
  th.children('span').html('&#11205;');
  th.next('section').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2 class="col-exp">Employment<span>&#11206;</span></h2>
<section id="employment">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>FakeSystems Inc</td>
      <td>Master Developer</td>
      <td>2000-2010</td>
      <td>Managed API routing by coordinating with foo and assessing the accuracy of returned data from 3rd party partners</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>WorseSystems Inc</td>
      <td>Lesser Developer</td>
      <td>1990-2000</td>
      <td>Made sites with Geocities and Angelfire that included tons of <code>blink</code> tags and gifs to make me look awesome</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
<h2 class="col-exp">Education<span>&#11206;</span></h2>
<section id="education">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Fake Institute of Fortitude</td>
      <td>1986-1990</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

Comment: Try closing and expanding a couple of times.

Comment: Thank you... I thought I tried that but I must've just had a typo. Much appreciated.

Comment: @phuzi OP only asked for "changing the arrow to down".

Comment: Alternatively, don't use an HTML entity but use `text()` with the character ⯅ directly…

Comment: True, but I bet that will be their next question.

Comment: Answer was what I was looking for. No further answers necessary. Thanks for the help.

Comment: *alternatively* just use two buttons and toggle them